# main() without return type on Clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

When using G++, one can write a program like so:

```
main() {
    // Something
}
```

And it just works. When using `-Wall` option, it generates a warning:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o test test.cpp
test.cpp:1:6: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type [-Wreturn-type]
 main() {
      ^
```

But, basically, it works. It doesn't work on Clang, though:

```
$ clang++ -o test test.cpp
test.cpp:1:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
main() {
^~~~
1 error generated.
```

And here's my question: is there any way to force Clang to behave like G++, i.e. allow `main()` with no return type?

<del>Also, here's an explanation why: on some algorithmic contests, it's convenient to do `#define int long long` - it just replaces all ints with long longs, so there's basically no problem with integer overflows (you don't need to remember about it => you don't waste time to debug your program when you have limited amount of time). Of course, you cannot write `long long main()`, so when using GCC you can just write `main()`, and it just works. What am I asking for is "what if you prefer Clang over GCC".</del> Appearantly, putting this information here makes a question "why `#define`s are bad and why contestants are idiots" instead of "is there a way to force Clang to accept `main()` function declaration without return type...

Comment: `#define int long long` - this is atrocious; please don't do that!  This is what `typedef`s are for.

Comment: Meh, I explained why I do that. I don't do that in "real" programs - it's only because I want to save time on contests. Anyway, `typedef`s aren't a solution - they don't allow me to define a type with name `int`. As I said before - it's because it saves time and thinking, nothing more.

Comment: What I mean is, you do `typedef int T`, and then use `T` everywhere.  What you're asking us is how to make gratuitously bad code even worse, rather than how to fix it.

Comment: @Oli Programming contestants usually do horrendous stuff like that to save typing. `#define vpll std::vector<std::pair<long, long>>` and so on.

Comment: @Cicada: Then frankly, they're idiots.  `typedef` would be no less typing, and it would be substantially safer!

Comment: @Oli Not disagreeing there :) Only explaining the "rationale" behind these heresies.

Comment: @m4tx: Re your edits.  You have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), hence the comments.  Your *actual* problem is "how do I succinctly modify the types of my calculations?", not "how do I force Clang to ignore a missing return type?".

Comment: I guess that you need only that for `main`. Then a simple `sed` script to add `int` before the (only) occurrence of `main` is *in practice* pragmatically sufficient (and would be simpler than trying to patch Clang source code).

Comment: In the same spirit of your practices, how about `#define main int main`? :)

Comment: @up well, it doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is:

> How do I tell clang to default declarations to `int`?

Then the answer is: it is **not** possible in C++ mode.
clang accepts such code in C mode *only*. This is standard conformant behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out the `int` has never been legal in C++. If you want to leave it out in clang then you must choose a language where it is legal to do. clang does not have any ability to disable or downgrade diagnostics that are errors by default nor does it support any C++ extension or mode where `int` can be left out.

C89 permits the type to be omitted, with `int` assumed:

```
⑆ clang -std=c89 -Weverything -x c - <<< 'main() {puts("hello, world"); }'
<stdin>:1:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'puts' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
main() {puts("hello, world"); }
        ^
1 warning generated.
⑆ ./a.out
hello, world
```

If you want to quickly modify your program to replace usages of `int` with another type, then you might want to write your program in the first place using a type alias (or typedef):

```
using my_int = int;
```

Since you clearly know ahead of time that you want to do this sort of thing then this should not be a problem. If for some reason you never can remember this until after you've written the program then you can use tools like 'search and replace'.

For example in vim you can do this to multiple files by creating an arglist of the files you want to modify and then running a replacement command on that list

```
:args *.cpp *.hpp
:argdo v/\<main\>/s/\<int\>/my_int/g
:wall
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `int32_t`?  It should be equivalent to `int` on most platforms.

```
$ echo '#include <stdint.h>\n#define int long long\nint32_t main() { }' | clang -xc -
$ ./a.out
```

Seems to be OK...

### Update

That said, I would rather recommend you to use something other than `int` for your long-enough integers.

```
typedef long long v; // 'v' for variable

v arr[10];
```

Two characters shorter!

Putting jokes aside, many of my friends who were enthusiastic to programming contests didn't really try to save time by resorting to these tricks.  You should brush up your skills of DP, Kruskal, Prim and Dijkstra.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I get the impression from the OP that portability, or safe/sane code are *not* among his priorities.